# Extract hours from csv using bash-script

Tags: bash, date, time

I have csv file having below details, want to fetch the details based on time like
if hour is in betwwen 10 and 18 it should print be as morning, and rest of lines print night.

```
time,id
2022-08-01T00:09:14+09:00,PKA990
2022-08-01T06:48:24+09:00,PKA990
2022-08-01T08:27:23+09:00,
2022-08-01T11:04:18+09:00,ABCD890
2022-08-01T11:23:22+09:00,ABCD890
2022-08-01T11:30:14+09:00,
2022-08-01T12:01:12+09:00,ABCD890
2022-08-01T15:11:59+09:00,JIKOPL8
2022-08-01T18:20:53+09:00,TUVNDGD
```

im expecting output be like

```
time,id,session
2022-08-01T00:09:14+09:00,PKA990,night
2022-08-01T06:48:24+09:00,PKA990,night
2022-08-01T08:27:23+09:00,LOADING,night
2022-08-01T11:04:18+09:00,ABCD890,morning
2022-08-01T11:23:22+09:00,ABCD890,morning
2022-08-01T11:30:14+09:00,LOADING,morning
2022-08-01T12:01:12+09:00,ABCD890,morning
2022-08-01T15:11:59+09:00,JIKOPL8,morning
2022-08-01T18:20:53+09:00,TUVNDGD,night
```

Please suggest.

Sorry i haved edited some rows .... when ever there is an blank it should fill with "LOADING"

apologize

Comment: please update the question to show the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Answer (score 0):

Here an `awk` solution:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

LC_ALL=en_US awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    $1 = $1
}
NR == 1 {
    print $0, "session", "day_of_week"
    next
}
$2 == "" {
    $2 = "LOADING"
}
{
    date_timestamp=sprintf("%04d %02d %02d 00 00 00", substr($1, 1, 4), substr($1, 6, 2), substr($1, 9, 2))
    day_of_week=tolower(strftime("%A", mktime(date_timestamp)))
    if ($1 ~ /^[-0-9]+T(10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17):/) {
        session="morning"
    } else {
        session="night"
    }
}
{
    print $0, session, day_of_week
}

' <"datetime.csv"
```

Output:

```
time,id,session,day_of_week
2022-08-01T00:09:14+09:00,PKA990,night,monday
2022-08-01T06:48:24+09:00,PKA990,night,monday
2022-08-01T08:27:23+09:00,LOADING,night,monday
2022-08-01T11:04:18+09:00,ABCD890,morning,monday
2022-08-01T11:23:22+09:00,ABCD890,morning,monday
2022-08-01T11:30:14+09:00,LOADING,morning,monday
2022-08-01T12:01:12+09:00,ABCD890,morning,monday
2022-08-01T15:11:59+09:00,JIKOPL8,morning,monday
2022-08-01T18:20:53+09:00,TUVNDGD,night,monday
```

Comment: UPDATED for adding `LOADING` in second column if empty

Comment: it is possible to get **dat_of_week** for "awk" solution ? @Arnaud Valmary

Comment: UPDATED : add day of week (in english with "`LC_ALL=en_US`") and with only the date part of timestamp

Answer (score 0):

A pure `bash` solution:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

INPUT_FILENAME="datetime.csv"
FLAG_FIRST=1
FS=","
OFS=","
while read -r LINE; do
    if [[ ${FLAG_FIRST} -eq 1 ]]; then
        printf "%s%s%s%s%s\n" "${LINE//${FS}/${OFS}}" "${OFS}" "session" "${OFS}" "day_of_week"
        FLAG_FIRST=0
        continue
    fi
    # Ignore empty lines
    [[ -z "${LINE}" ]] && continue
    # If LINE ends with coma (assume id field is empty):
    #   put "LOADING" token at end of line
    [[ "${LINE}" =~ ${FS}$ ]] && LINE+="LOADING"
    # LC_ALL=en_US to obtains day of week in english (I'am french)
    # Use ${LINE%%T*} to use date field without hour and timezone
    DAY_OF_WEEK=$(LC_ALL=en_US date +%A --date "${LINE%%T*}")
    # In english, day of week begins with an uppercase letter:
    #   use a coma after variable name to put it in lowercase
    if [[ "${LINE}" =~ ^[-0-9]+T(10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17): ]]; then
        SESSION="morning"
    else
        SESSION="night"
    fi
    printf "%s%s%s%s%s\n" "${LINE//${FS}/${OFS}}" "${OFS}" "${SESSION}" "${OFS}" "${DAY_OF_WEEK,}"
done < <(cat "${INPUT_FILENAME}"; echo)
```

Output:

```
time,id,session,day_of_week
2022-08-01T00:09:14+09:00,PKA990,night,monday
2022-08-01T06:48:24+09:00,PKA990,night,monday
2022-08-01T08:27:23+09:00,LOADING,night,monday
2022-08-01T11:04:18+09:00,ABCD890,morning,monday
2022-08-01T11:23:22+09:00,ABCD890,morning,monday
2022-08-01T11:30:14+09:00,LOADING,morning,monday
2022-08-01T12:01:12+09:00,ABCD890,morning,monday
2022-08-01T15:11:59+09:00,JIKOPL8,morning,monday
2022-08-01T18:20:53+09:00,TUVNDGD,night,monday
```

Comment: Thanks, 

I have edited my question. 
apologies

Comment: UPDATED for adding `LOADING` in second column if empty

Comment: thanks, @Arnaud Valmary

is it possible to add last field as **weekday** of time ? like 


**2022-08-01T00:09:14+09:00,PKA990,night,monday ?**

Comment: **2022-08-01T00:09:14+09:00** , weekday of "2022-08-01" is Monday.

Comment: Updated with day of week

Comment: Update : Now I use only the date to determine the day of week